# Geometric mean intuition and interpretation

Tags: interpretation, geometric-mean

When simple mean is generally quite an intuitive term, and may be interpreted among others as *average value* in terms of distance, *central value* in terms of weight, *expected value* in terms of probability calculus, what would be intuitive interpretations for [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean)?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of interpretations that I'm aware of:

- One dimension of the hypercube with the same volume as the hyperrectangle defined by given numbers.
- If you take the logarithm of both sides in the GM expression, you'll see that it resembles the expression $e^{E[\log X]}$, sometimes called *log-average*.
- An intuitive example would be the average growth rate during years. e.g. let' say your investment doubled this year and tripled the following year. what would be the average growth rate per year of your investment? ($\sqrt{2 \times 3}$)